# Create Visual Studio for Mac extension (.mpack) file

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin

I am trying to create a new project template extension. I have followed the steps mentioned in the link below to create the template. It works fine on my Visual Studio as it is adding the configuration in my Visual Studio custom folder template.

https://lastexitcode.com/blog/2017/11/12/TemplateCreatorForVisualStudioMac/

Now I need to pack this project template and ship it to others with the extension type of extension_name.mpack.

Could you please provide the steps to create the mpack file from the template files.

Comment: Yes, you can refer to [this guide](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/creating-visual-studio-for-mac-extensions-a-complete-guide.aspx) for more details on how to create the mpack file from the template files.

Comment: The above guide is using AddinMaker plugin, but it is outdated and not working on VS 2022.

Comment: Looks like this is not supported yet in VS 2022, please refer to [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthough-create-extension-pack?view=vs-2022).